# Dynamically added class not responding as a selector in another jQuery script?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML document with a layout similar to this:

```
<div id="main">
   <section class="page1 active">...</section>
   <section class="page2">...</section>
   <section class="page3">...</section>
   ...
</div>
```

The 'pagex' classes on each of the sections are fixed and do not change, while the 'active' class is applied and removed by this portion of jQuery code in an entirely different script:

```
$('a, section').removeClass('active');
$('a[data-index="'+activePage+'"], section[data-index="'+activePage+'"]').addClass('active');
}
```

Where `activePage` is an unrelated variable. Since each section takes up 100% of the viewport, only a section which has the class 'active' is visible to the user.

What I am trying to do is use `.active` as a jQuery selector hook to style child elements inside the active section, but it's simply not working.

Inside each section, a template similar to this occurs:

```
<header class="title" data-sheet="1">Launch Count</header>
<div class="dropdown">
<span>Total</span>
<ul>
    <li data-sheet="1">Total</li>
    <li data-sheet="2">Falcon 9</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="contents">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="metric" data-sheet="1">12</td>
        <td class="metric" data-sheet="2">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="unit" data-sheet="1">Launches</td>
        <td class="unit" data-sheet="2">Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<footer>
<p data-sheet="1">Test</p>
<p data-sheet="2">Another test</p>              

</footer>
```

Say this particular template is inside the section with a class of `page3`, I can use this rule:

```
$('section.page3 [data-sheet]').not('li').not("[data-sheet*='1']").hide();
```

To hide all elements within `section` with a class of `page3` that contain the attribute `data-sheet` that are not equal to 1.

But, as I said before, I'm trying to use .active as a hook to make sure this rule only applies to the section that is active, like this:

```
 $('section.active [data-sheet]').not('li').not("[data-sheet*='1']").hide();
```

But it simply doesn't work. Nothing is hidden, like it was before. Why the hell is this happening?

Comment: are you sure that you are doing it after the active class is added

Comment: No I'm not. How can I be sure?

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PBK7u/1/) works but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PBK7u/2/) doesn't

Comment: you need to share complete code for us to see what is happening

Comment: where the active class is added and where the visibility is set

Comment: I simply cannot add the complete code. It's over 2000 lines long and completely irrelevant.

Comment: then add a line `alert($('section.active').length)` before the `$('section.active [data-sheet]').not('li').not("[data-sheet*='1']").hide();` line and see what is alerted